# Newton's Method Annuity Due Equation

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

I'm having a really hard time with a homework problem I've been assigned for my numerical analysis class. It's supposed to be a Newton's method question, but I don't see how to use the method here:

The accumulated value of a savings account based on regular periodic payments can be determined from the annuity due equation:

```
A = P/i[(1+i)^n-1].
```

In this equation, A is the amount in the account, P is the amount regularly deposited and i is the rate of interest per period for the n deposit periods. If one wished to have an account valued at 750 000 in 20 years and you wish to deposit $1500 per month, what is the minimal interest rate at which this amount can be invested, assuming that the interest is compounded monthly?

What I have is that

```
750 000 = 1500/i[(1+i)^(20*12) - 1]
```

Because it is a monthly deposit. So my Maple input looks like this:

```
Newton(1500*((1+x)^(20*12)-1)/x-750000, x = 1500, output = sequence)
```

Am I even on the right track? This yields some interesting output to say the least. I'm not sure how to apply this word problem to Newton's method, and I'm also unsure on how to go about choosing a good starting x. Any advice?

Comment: In one place you have 7500000 and in another you have 750000. Which is it?

Comment: I don't understand the $x=1500$. Your initial estimate for the interest rate is $150000$ percent?

Comment: It should be 750 000, sorry. And is that what the x0 represents here? I'm legitimately confused with Newton's method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have the formula:

$$A = P \dfrac{(1 + i)^n - 1}{i}$$

We are given $A = 750000$, $P = 1500$ and $n = 20$, so we have:

$$\dfrac{1500 \left((1+i)^{20} - 1\right)}{i} = 750000$$

We can rewrite this as:

$$f(i) = 1500 \left((1+i)^{20} - 1\right) - 750000 i = 0$$

So, we are asked to  use Newton's Method to find the interest, $i$, where there is a zero. This is equivalent to determining the interest rate needed to have the amount $750000$ after $20$ years.

Newton's iteration is given by:

$$i_{n+1} = i_n - \dfrac{f(i_n)}{f'(i_n)}$$

Thus, we have:

$$i_{n+1} = i_{n} - \dfrac{1500 \left((i_{n}+1)^{20}-1\right)-750000 i_{n}}{30000 (i_{n}+1)^{19}-750000}$$

Choosing a starting point of $i_0 = 0.24$, after 6-steps, we converge to:

$$i = 0.280957$$

Lets check this result:

$$A = P \dfrac{(1 + i)^n - 1}{i} = 1500\dfrac{(1 + 0.280957)^{20} - 1}{0.280957} = 750001$$

The bank would likely fire you for going over by a buck!

Comment: In your equation, you have n being 20 for 20 years, but deposits are made monthly. Why is this?

Comment: @humdiddlediddle: I am no financial expert, but it is for two reasons, because using 240 makes it unsolvable and because of what [*terms*](http://www.mathinary.com/future_value_of_an_annuity.jsp) is defined as (it is an AND condition, see site). Even if these numbers are off (try solving this with 240, for example), at least you see what they had in mind for using Newton's Method. Regards

Comment: Nice work with good ole' Newton!

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks! Do you think Newton had his $401k$ in mind when he figured it out? :) Have a great day!

Comment: Hahahaha! Not at all! You too: MTMOT: make the most of today!

Comment: Ahhh I see. I had been trying pretty much exactly this but with 240, and as you say, it is indeed unsolvable, at least as far as I could tell. Thanks a lot for the solution, it makes sense. Why did you choose .24 though? Just a random guess, or did you try other values as well?

Comment: I plotted the function and pretty much chose that randomly. When you implement it, play around with different starting values. Newton's is very stable, although has some issue points. However, it will likely converge, albeit using a different number of steps, for almost any starting value. Regards

Answer (score 0):

We can't solve this equation using Newton's method neither Fixed-point method, because it's not convergente.

**PROOF** for Fixed-point

Suppose
$$g(x) = 0.002\left[(1+x)^{240} - 1 \right]$$
then
$$ g'(x) = 240\times 0.002 (1+x)^{239}$$ 
using Scilab to plot the graph of $g(x)$ we found that $x$ must be betwine $0.005$ and $0.006$
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OKZW.png)

So $g'(0.005) >1 $ 
$\square$

You can use the bisection technique to solve this problem, the following was a scilab code used to solve this problem

```
 // Solving Annuity Due Equation using besiction Technique
 a = 0.005
 b = 0.006
 c = a + 0.5*(b-a)
 eps = 0.0000000001
 i = 1
 N = 1000
 while %t
  if( (b-a) < eps )
      break
  end
  c = a + 0.5*( b-a )
  fc = 0.002*(( 1 + c )^240 - 1 )/c - 1
  if( fc < 0)
      a = c
  elseif( fc > 0 )
      b = c
  else
      break
   end
 if( i > N )
      break
  end
  i = i + 1
 end

 disp('i =')
 disp(c)
 disp('Number of iteration')
 disp(i)
```

Output:

```
 i =   
 0.0055508  
 Number of iteration   
 25.
```